# ESlint Plugin That Enforces Function Parameter Names

Tags: javascript, eslint, styling, eslintrc

I am looking for an ESlint plugin that can enforce function parameter names with a regex in javascript. e.g: `^my[A-Z]`.

e.g:

```
const doSomething = (myUserInput) => {} // Ok 

const doSomethingWrong = (userInput) => {} // Wrong, param should has a prefix "my"
```

I saw that typescript-eslint has an option to do it. However, my project is mainly in JS and only use eslint. https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/naming-convention/. The other option would be to write a custom elsint which would be my last resource.